# Find and use the path of a file?

Tags: shell, rename, filenames, quoting

I'm trying to find the path of a file and move it.

When I try `realpath`, it is not useful.

For example : I want to move the file `All Hail the Generalist - Vikram Mansharamani - Harvard Business Review.html`

Using `realpath`:

```
realpath 'All Hail the Generalist - Vikram Mansharamani - Harvard Business Review.html
/home/x/Downloads/All Hail the Generalist - Vikram Mansharamani - Harvard Business Review.html
```

But I can't do :

```
mv /home/x/Downloads/All Hail the Generalist - Vikram Mansharamani - Harvard Business Review.html /home/
```

I need something like that :

```
mv  /home/x/Downloads/All\ Hail\ the\ Generalist\ -\ Vikram\ Mansharamani\ -\ Harvard\ Business\ Review.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
mv '/home/x/Downloads/All Hail the Generalist - Vikram Mansharamani - Harvard Business Review.html' /home/
```

Notice the single quotes to include the full filename and prevent shell parsing of the string.

Comment: Hey man !!! 
You are rigth!
it works !! tkx :)